# Images from SD Card is not loaded in the WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview, filenotfoundexception, android-external-storage

I have the following HTML code loaded into a `String`.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page2.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page3.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page4.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to load the html into a `WebView` in my app as follows.

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

I have the following permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and made sure the permissions are granted.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I went through many answers in SO (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055471/3145960)), but cannot seem to find a solution to load the images from SD Card into my `WebView`. I also made sure that the images are not corrupted (I can view those images using the Gallery app). Any thoughts?

I did not find any error in the logcat. However, a possible logcat related to this problem might be the following (I am not sure though).

```
W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.example.myapp/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
```

Here is how it looks like when the `WebView` tries to load the images.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: In my case, images loaded when i edit html image paths
String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ basePath + "/test.jpg";
You can edit your html file text dynamically with imagePath.

Comment: `src="file://storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg"` For that to work it should be `src="file:///storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg"`.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg` That is an impossible path. Which also has noting to do wit a removable micro SD card. You can check with the FIle class that the file does not exists in that path. Try `File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg"); if ( file.existst()) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg` You might have succes with `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Page1.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` I used the `/sdcard/Downloads` which seems to solve the problem. So the final HTML which I generated that worked is the following.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://sdcard/Download/Page1.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://sdcard/Download/Page2.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://sdcard/Download/Page3.jpg"/>
        <img style="width:100%" src="file://sdcard/Download/Page4.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```